# This is the pen which is convenient

Tags: sentence-meaning, definite-article

There is a sentence:

> This is the pen which is convenient.

Is it a proper sentence if, for instance, the listener understands I mean the pens in the room, but I didn't mention the pens before? Which meanings can it have:

1. This is the only pen in the universe which is convenient?
2. This is the only pen in the room which is convenient?
3. This is the pen in the room, which is convenient and there can be other convenient in the room as well?
4. This is one of the convenient pens in the universe?

Comment: I think; This is the only pen (among multiple) in the room which is convenient

Comment: You don't need to have mentioned the pens before. Don't get too hung up on that.

Answer (score 1):

*This is the pen which is convenient* is not  grammatical.

*Given a choice of pens*, one that is easy to use and one that is difficult to use, a native speaker would say

**This is the convenient pen.**

or

**This is the pen *that's* convenient.  This is the pen that is easy to use.**

"Which" is used to connect a modifying phrase back to an antecedent noun. The phrase states some fact about the noun, but not a fact that *differentiates* the noun from other nouns of its ilk.  When the fact differentiates, we use "that" instead.

> This is a pen, which can be used for writing love letters,
>   diaries, and other items where typing would seem impersonal.
>
> This is a pen that has red ink (i.e. as opposed to the usual blue or black)

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, and I think there is a lot of useful information in it, but I think "This is the pen which is convenient" is not ungrammatical. It's true that *that* is more common nowadays, but *which* is not incorrect in the example sentence, in my opinion.

Comment: Oh, pretty interesting point about 'which' and 'that'. I have never thought about it)) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Damkerng: I'm not one to obey prescriptive rules about language, but instead understand the language to be a living thing. "which" and "that" are often interchanged, but usually by people who, *when writing*, are trying to remember what they were taught fuzzily in school.   I bet if you gathered your data from spoken English alone, in everyday contexts where the speaker is not trying to sound educated, "that" would be used (grammatically) to introduce a differentiating relative clause.

Comment: Also, in the parsing rhythms of natural speech, where the speaker is speaking naturally, and not trying to sound educated but is talking comfortably, the word "that" would almost be "swallowed", and pronounced "th't", a hallmark feature of a natural grammatical use versus a prescriptive one.

Comment: I understand you and largely agree with you. I just saw your comment asking for the reason of the downvote, and I thought this might be the reason. Practically, I would use "that" there myself, too. However, to say that it's not grammatical is perhaps a bit too strong, imho. (I'm more comfortable with "not recommended".) The downvote was retracted. I think we can't know the real reason unless they tell us.

Comment: I once got a letter from a job applicant who explained why he wanted to relocate to the Philadelphia area. He wrote: "My girlfriend, which lives in New Jersey." (New Jersey is just across the river.) Funny thing, he was trying to sound educated. This phenomenon, where *which* replaces natural *that* (or in the case of that letter, the word "who"!) is entirely a product of the education system, a legacy of (misguided) prescriptive rule-making, and poor student memories. Many people say "I" when they would like to say "me" (*He sat with she and I*), overruling their natural linguistic instincts.

Comment: @TRomano - As Swan writes in his *Practical English Usage (2005), "we often use *that* instead of *who* or *which*, especially in an informal style: *This is the key that opens the garage*. However, he (and other writers) give many examples of *which* in defining relative clauses, eg, *This is the key which opens the garage. *That* is fine, but *which* is not in any way ungrammatical.

Comment: "This is the key that opens the garage" is not an informality, *pace* Swan. That Swan considers "which" the more formal of the two helps me make my point, that the use of "which* in restrictive clauses is perceived as the more correct choice, but it ain't.

Comment: @TRomano - BSwan did not claim that *that* was an informality. he said that we often use it **especially** in an informal style.  You did not say you thought the perception of *which* as more correct was wrong. You said it was ungrammatical, which it isn't.

Comment: @tunny:  Is the asterisk there (in "*that") Swan's indication that he regards 'that' to be incorrect or substandard|informal? I am somewhat familiar with the history of the that|which debate. I am not a prescriptivist. I believe 'which' in restrictive clauses is the product of a prescriptivist educational system, though I will have to put off documenting that claim until my dotage.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the pen which is convenient.

Right now, only one pen is convenient.  This is that pen.

I don't know why you're considering the difference between the set of pens in the room and the set of pens in the universe.  The room and the universe aren't mentioned in the sentence.  A listener doesn't have any reason to think about either.

I see only two sets of pens in the sentence: the set of all pens and the set of convenient pens.  The set of all pens contains, well, *all* pens -- even pens that exist outside of the universe.  The set of convenient pens, according to this sentence, contains exactly one pen -- just this pen.

If I have to choose from your four options, I'll choose option 1.  In fact, I'd rather edit that option:  1. This is the only pen <strike>in the universe</strike> which is convenient.

What if more than one pen happens to be convenient, and this is just one of them?  In that case, your sentence becomes:

> This is a pen which is convenient.

Right now, some number of pens are convenient.  This is just one of those pens.